# Задать свойство для всех элементов, независимо от тега

Tags: html, css

Можно ли задать свойство для всех элементов с заданным родителем, независимо от тега?

У меня есть свойство:

```
div.test > div > div {
  ...
}
```

Он применяется ко всем элементам типа div прямым родителем которого является тоже div, а его родителем - div класса test. А нужно переделать так:

```
div.test > div > [любой элемент] {
  ...
}
```

Такое возможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.test > div > *{

}
```

Так?

Comment: Работает. То есть в CSS можно использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: А при чем тут регулярки?
Регулярки можно использовать http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern

Comment: Я подразумевал в CSS. Ну, возможность писать звездочку, имея ввиду любое значение, напоминает именно регулярки.

Answer (score 0):

На поставленный вопрос правильно ответил [[@zloctb](/users/6113/zloctb)](/users/6113/zloctb), но **очень** настоятельная рекомендация так стили не писать.

Подавляющее большинство стилей наследуется от родителей (будет применено ко всем дочерним элементам родителя), что выполнит ту же задачу.

Использовать селектор "*" зачастую не рекомендуют ввиду относительно медленной выборки элементов.

Если немного точнее опишите задачу (какие именно стили должны применяться ко всем элементам  `div'a`), я уверен здесь подскажут более красивое решение.
В большинстве случаев используют, так называемый, `reset.css` - стили для сбрасывания настроек браузера по умолчанию. 
Вот простейший пример как могут выглядеть наследуемые стили:

```
    //reset.css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,
acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,
sub,sup,tt,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,
tr,th,td
      {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        outline:0;
        font-style:inherit;
        font-family:inherit;
      }
    //далее стили для конкретного блока
    div.test > div {
      color:#000;
      font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Garuda,sans-serif;
      font-size:14px;
    }
    //стили размера и цвета шрифта будут применяться и к div вложенному в div.test и ко всем внутренним элементам
```

Старайтесь пользоваться наследованием стилей, а не применять одни и те же стили для всех элементов.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Я использую этот стиль для улучшения `SplitLayoutPanel` из GWT. Первый и второй div генерирует GWT, а внутри может быть всё, что угодно, т.е.

    div.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel > div > * {
      ...
    }